# Each node must be labeled with a zone attribute - but how?

Tags: couchdb

I have 3 nodes in each zone (2 zones) and all nodes are listed in _membership.

```
[cluster]
q=3
r=2
w=2
n=3
z=2
placement = az1:3,az2:3
```

I'm stuck with what PUT/POST command I need to run to label a node with a zone attribute. Below is from the docs:

> First, each node must be labeled with a zone attribute. This defines which zone each node is in. You do this by editing the node’s document in the /nodes database, which is accessed through the “back-door” (5986) port. Add a key value pair of the form:
>
> "zone": "metro-dc-a"

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this point of the docs [4.4.4. Specifying database placement](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/cluster/sharding.html#specifying-database-placement) the mechanism for setting the zone of a node is defined.

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5986/_nodes/<node-name> \
-d '{ \
    "_id": "<node-name>",
    "_rev": "<rev>",
    "zone": "<zone-name>"
    }'
```